# com.android.tools.r8.internal.m1: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

When I try to build apk or simply build the project then it is giving me this error:
`com.android.tools.r8.internal.m1: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)`
But when I connect my phone through USB and manually run the app then it is working properly.

Yes, I found few similar questions but none worked for me.

Build.gradle

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

}

android {
compileSdk 31

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abhaysapp.vaccination"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap_info.txt'
        exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/*'
    }

}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0-alpha03'
androidTestImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-android:1.9.0"
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:4.2.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0-alpha05'
implementation 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.3';
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
```

}

Comment: The reason it works when "I connect my phone through USB and manually run the app" is most likely due to Android Studio injecting the `minSdk` of the attached phone when debugging directly from within Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Update the version of the mockk library

from

```
io.mockk:mockk-android:1.9.0"
```

to

```
"io.mockk:mockk-android:1.12.2"
```

then rebuild project